# How to add a value of a point on y axis in a PLOT in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis

For example many points and I want to display them in a Plot.
I want to appear the value of point  on y axis, for example:
the point ( 4, 2.5), I want to display the 2.5 on the Y axis and a small line between the point and its Y value
[image]

PS: I want to appear the value on the left of y-axis

Comment: Matplotlib is a Python package wholly unrelated to MATLAB. I've removed the tag

Answer (score 2):

Adding ticks to an axis can be done with [`yticks`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yticks.html) and then add the label using [`yticklabels`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yticklabels.html). In both cases, first call it with an output argument to collect the current ticks/labels, then add the desired one.

```matlab
yt = yticks;
yt = [yt, 2.5];
yticks(yt);
ylabels = yticklabels;
ylabels = {ylabels, "2.5"}; % You might need to sort this one
yticklabels(ylabels)
```

Alternatively, if you e.g. want to make it stand out using a different colour, use [`text()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html); `text(-0.1, 2.5, "2.5")` or something, where the `-0.1` should plot it to the left of the axis.

Drawing a horizontal line is as easy as using `plot` again: `plot([0, 4], [2.5, 2.5])`.

Comment: r.e. your last sentence, if you use `line` instead of `plot` then I think you can avoid requiring `hold on` in between (untested)

Comment: @Wolfie but `line` goes all the way right? As in: infinite in the specified direction. OP shows it ending at x=4 in their question.

Comment: line shares the same syntax as `plot` for simple things, then you just have to use all of the explicit name-value inputs if you want the styling options. But `line([0,4],[2.5,2.5])` would do the same as `plot([0,4],[2.5,2.5])` - it's just more primitive so doesn't need the `hold`. It's `yline` (as in my answer) which goes all the way across the axes. This is a tangent, probably saves less effort than this comment has caused :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate option which looks slightly different but is very easy to use: `yline`

Plot setup:

```
x = 4; y = 2.5;
figure(1); clf;
plot( x, y, 'or' ); % plot point
```

Adding the labelled horizontal line:

```
yline( y, 'r-', num2str(y) );
```

Result:

[image: plot]

Similarly you could use `xline` to add the orthogonal label

```
xline( x, 'r-', num2str(x), 'LabelOrientation', 'horiz' );
```

[image: plot 2]

*`yline` and `xline` were introduced in R2018b*

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution using [yticks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yticks.html?searchHighlight=yticks&s_tid=srchtitle_yticks_1) proposed by @Adriaan. In terms of escalate the plot, the example use a object.

```
x = 4; y = 2.5;

f = figure(1);
ax = gca;
plot(ax, [0, x], [y, y], 'r-' );
yticks(ax, y);
```